# HEAD is not initialized at vscode extension startup

Tags: typescript, git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-git

I need to get the commit hash from the HEAD for each workspace when loading my extension, at vscode startup. For some reason, the HEAD was not initialized at boot time. If I add a 1 second sleep, then HEAD becomes initialized. Why is this happening? I suspect that I need to wait for the add-on-git/workspace/etc to initialize and add handler for some event.

Representation:

```
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // if uncomment this, HEAD becomes initialized
    const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension<GitExtension>('vscode.git')!.exports;
    const gitApi = gitExtension.getAPI(1);

    for (const workSpaceFolder of vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders || []) {
        const rootPath = workSpaceFolder.uri.fsPath;
        const repo = await gitApi.openRepository(vscode.Uri.parse(rootPath));

        const head = repo!.state.HEAD;

        console.log(head); // undefined
    }
}
```

part of package.json:

```
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.62.0"
    },
    "activationEvents": [
        "onStartupFinished"
    ],
    "extensionDependencies": [
        "vscode.git"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the event `onStartupFinished` is triggered too early for your needs: when that event is triggered, `GitExtension` hasn't necessarily been initalized or activated.

I haven't delved in vscode extension code yet, but looking at the code for `extensions/git` in [vscode's repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode), you can see how [`GitExtension` is initialized](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9919c760c21316dcd0efa535db4fd32ef3e8051c/extensions/git/src/api/git.d.ts#L266)(*) :

```js
export type APIState = 'uninitialized' | 'initialized';

// ...

export interface API {
    readonly state: APIState;
    readonly onDidChangeState: Event<APIState>;
    readonly onDidPublish: Event<PublishEvent>;
    readonly git: Git;
    // ...
}

export interface GitExtension {

    readonly enabled: boolean;
    readonly onDidChangeEnablement: Event<boolean>;

    // ...
    getAPI(version: 1): API;
}
```

Judging by the type declaration, you should probably check if `GitExtension` is enabled, then check if the `API` object reurned by `getAPI()` is initialized (`API.state === 'initialized'`).

In both cases, you can register a listener on `GitExtension.onDidChangeEnablement()` and `API.onDidChangeState()` to have a chance to run the initialization code for your extension after `GitExtension` has finished initializing.

---

(*) *note:* commit `9919c760c2` referenced in the code link above is the state of `master` as I see it on github, on 2022-06-06 at 6 am UTC